# Qt6 Android Project 'error: '__nomerge__' attribute cannot be applied to a declaration' when moving from ndk 22 to ndk 25

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, qt6

I have an android project setup with cmake in Qt6.  This project generates a .so that I use with my Android Studio project.  I've been using ndk 22 and its been working fine, but now I need to move to ndk 25.

In my build settings I updated ANDROID_NDK to ndk 25, updated ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL to 25 and changed CMAKE_TOOl_CHAIN_FILE to point to the android.toolchain.cmake in ndk 25.
[image: Build setup]
[image: Build setup 2]

When I build now I get the following error:  In file included from C:/Libs/AndroidSDK/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/local/include\stdlib.h:31:
C:/Libs/AndroidSDK/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include\stdlib.h:44:44: error: '**nomerge**' attribute cannot be applied to a declaration
__noreturn void abort(void) **attribute**((**nomerge**));

This must be a configuration mistake.  Are there any other fields I should be update to change over to ndk25?  I'm not sure where to go next.